# Google Analytics Reporting API & Search Console - Dimensions & Metrics

Tags: google-analytics

As the Google Search Console is now fully integrated into GA...

(...see http://searchengineland.com/google-search-console-metrics-now-deeply-integrated-google-analytics-249334 ...)

...we would like to get access to e.g. the search terms via API (e.g. to access the data via spreadsheets). Therefore we want to know if this is possible at all - and if yes, which dimensions & metrics can be accessed.

The corresponding API page doesn´t help atm:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=page_tracking,content_grouping,channel_grouping

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

1. The first solution you posted yourself. The developers.google.com link is showing you exactly, what dimensions and metrics can be combined.
2. Try it yourself with the query explorer: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Just add the metrics/dimensions you could probably need and try out what works.

If you need Search Console Data you should use the Search Console API ;)
There you go: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/webmasters/v3/

The GA interface can show you the data, but GA is not the source of the data. And they also don't have a copy of it. You will need to use the right api.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your reply! 
Actually - that´s why I asked ;). The developers.google.com didn´t help here and neither did the query explorer.
What I´m searching for is a way to get access to the data of the google search console...and I can´t find corresponding (and working) dimensions/metrics...

Comment: Just added an update to my answer, sorry for misunderstanding your request. But you should know, the GA API only has GA data, not search console data. GA displays them by accessing the data in search console api.